# Does deleting a repository remove files as well?

Tags: svn, repository, redhat

I have a svn repo setup on one of our web servers? The repo currently has website files in it. If I delete the repo with the appropriate svn delete command from command line, will all the files be deleted as well?

Comment: Can you give an example of the layout in the file system? How does the web server serve files from the repo? Does it look into the repo or did you a checkout somewhere?

Comment: @codename32 file will be removed in the latest revision (i.e. won't exist) but is still available in repository history.

Comment: What do you mean by "delete repo"? If you delete the whole repo, nothing will be available (any more), only the latest checked out content. Or do you mean "delete folder (even top folder) in the repo"? You have all the time the content of the repository (with history) and the content of the local checkout ...

Comment: My objective is to leave the web directory(subfolders and files) intact (keep directory and files on physical disk) and recreate the repository with a different name and settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you delete a file from the repository, it will be deleted in any working copies which are checked out from that repository *when the working copy is next updated*. Unless there are local modifications to that file - in which case, the file will be unversioned, but not deleted from disk.

Nothing is truly deleted in Subversion, it's only removed from the `HEAD` revision. You can always get it back.